# Какой предлог использовать в предложении — "о" или "об"?

Tags: грамматика, предлоги

Всем прекрасно известно следующее правило в русском языке:

> Предлог "о" пишется перед словами, начинающимися с согласной, предлог "об" - перед словами, начинающимися с гласной

Но, какой предлог следует использовать в случае, если за ним стоит английское слово в кавычках?
Допустим:

> Несколько вопросов (об/о) "if"

> Есть ли в статье (об/о) "switch" какие-либо неточности?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Руководствуйтесь тем же самым правилом. Можно лишь добавить в него оговорку, что важна не первая *буква* слова, а, скорее, первый *звук*, ибо, как известно, во многих языках бывают непроизносимыми и первые буквы. Пример (для английского языка): *hour*.
Соответственно:

> Несколько вопросов об "if".
>
> Есть ли в статье о "switch" какие-либо неточности?

Comment: Согласен. "Об if" - [абыф]. О Yellow Submarine, о user-е (как о юге), о Ватсоне, об Уотсоне.